# Lookup in CSV file is failing

Tags: php, csv

I have a form where the user enters their first and last names. I want to check if their full name is present in my CSV file, which I use to store all current members / users of my form. The format in which data is stored is  `firstname,lastname`. And if they are present, I want to print out `You are already a member`.

But that is not what I see in output, when I run my code. It doesn't output that, even if I input names which are present in the CSV file.

Here is my source code:

```
$JLMembers = Array();

// Open the file of Members
if ($handle = fopen("JLMembers.csv", "r")) {
    // Get the next CSV line
    while ($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) {

        // Add that line to the array
        array_push($JLMembers, $data);
    }
}

foreach($JLMembers as $JLMember) {
    $FirstName = $_GET['FirstName'];
    $CurrentMemberFirstName = $JLMembers[0];

    if ($FirstName === $CurrentMemberFirstName) {

        foreach($JLMembers as $JLMember) {
            $SecondName = $_GET['LastName'];
            $CurrentMemberSecondName = $JLMembers[1];

            if ($SecondName === $CurrentMemberSecondName) {
                print "<br>You are already a member<br>";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Post some code maybe...

Comment: Please post your code and some sample data to reproduce the issue.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! [Please don't post your code as an image.](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3933332)

Comment: Do you know how foreach works anyway? why do you have a foreach inside another foreach with the parent information?

Comment: Build an array containing `first` and `lastname` and use `array_search` to find if your `$key` (string of first and lastname) is inside the array.

Comment: 1) You can do your checks in one foreach loop, otherwise the first and last name could possible be from another person 2) Have you checked for errors? Checked if you got all data from the csv correctly in your array?

Comment: How would I do both my checks in one foreach loop? Again, I apologise, I'm very new to php and coding in general.

Comment: You dont. You'd finish building the array, then search within it. Either via loops or let `array_search` do the job.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using `$JLMembers[0]`, which contains the first row of the CSV, when you should be using `$JLMember[0]`, which contains the first column of the current row in the `foreach` loop. And you don't need two loops, just compare both columns in one loop.

The code should be:

```
$FirstName = $_GET['FirstName'];
$LastName = $_GET['LastName'];
foreach ($JLMembers as $JLMember) {
    if ($FirstName == $JLMember[0] && $LastName == $JLMember[1]) {
        echo "<br>You are a member<br>";
        break; // Exit the loop once we found a match
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Now I need to work out how to stop it from saying I'm a member when the first and last name are from two different people.

Comment: It shouldn't do that. It only matches when the names match in a single row, not in different rows.

Comment: That was a problem with your nested loops, not my code.

Comment: It only works if the name I type in is the first first name (first name at the top of the column). Any other first names and it doesn't work. Also, it says I'm a member even if the second name is completely wrong, providing the first name is correct.

Comment: I had a typo. `$LastName = $JLMember[1]` should be `$LastName == $JLMember[1]`.

Comment: Thats fixed the problem of it saying I'm a member even if the second name is completely wrong. But it still only works for the name thats top of the list in the csv file.

Comment: Check the CSV file, make sure there are no spaces around the names. You could use `trim($JLMember[0])` and `trim($JLMember[1])` to discard the spaces.

Comment: Yeah I've checked the CSV file, there aren't any spaces around the names. I took out `break;` and it seems to be working now.

Comment: Then I can't see how this loop can fail to match later entries.

Comment: I see the problem. I forgot to pub braces around the `if` body.

Comment: Actually, I had the close brace, but not the open brace. I wonder how it ran at all if you didn't fix that.